# Entering Keystrokes with WebDriver/Seleneium without an Object to send the command to

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having trouble figuring out how to switch to a popup window built within a webpage and the easy way around that fix is to just hit the "enter" key.  However, the way the class works is that the command:

```
Sendkeys.Keys("<insert Key>");
```

Expects there to be some type of textbox to send it to (unless I do not understand it well enough), where I just need to hit the enter key, as if just stroking it on the keyboard.  Is this possible in Selenium or the Windows namespaces?

**EDIT**

I did not have the code in which I am working with, so I will show it now:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_c_btnPost_btn")).Click();
```

This command forces the window to pop up.  To be clear, this is not another window in my browser, it is a window that pops up within the webpage, which is where my problem came from.  The form looks like:

[image]

After this window pops up, I want to hit the enter key to simply select "OK," without have to actually select the window. However, I would love someone to explain how to select the window as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to send keys to the `body` element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys("Keys here");
```

Though, if this is an alert, *switch to it and accept it*:

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

You can also send the keys to that "window wrapper" popup you've shown on the screenshot:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id^=RadWindowWrapper]")).SendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Or, locate the OK button inside and click it:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'RadWindowWrapper')]//*[. = 'OK']")).Click();
```

Comment: Ah, that is my problem.  I am too unfamiliar with the calls that are not `By.XPath`, `By.Id`, and `By.Name`.  Thank you and i will try this right away!

Comment: Additionally, do you know of a source that lists the value of the keys, I saw an example online for the enter key, but I would like to find a resource, if you know of any.  Thank you again!

Comment: unfortunately, the website is private, but I will provide the example.

Comment: I believe this may be an alert, however, I do not really know what the difference between that and window are.

Comment: @Alexce I get an error saying that "No alert is present"

Comment: @Alexce Doesn't seem like this is an Alert issue, could you perhaps help me find out what <tag> to use to select it as a new window like the <body> tag in your first example?

Comment: @Alexce Works like a charm!  Thank you for all your help, always!